# I am trying to replace a BufferedImage in my code with an animated gif

Tags: java, swing, animation, drawimage, imageobserver

Currently in my code I have a BufferedImage drawn like:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.transform(at); //at is an AffineTransform that just rotates the .gif
g2d.drawImage(sharkie, xCenter-5*radius, yCenter-3*radius, 10*radius, 6*radius, null);
```

I already have it fully functioning as a BufferedImage, but as expected it shows only the first frame. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way that is analogous to BufferedImage that works for animated gifs. I can't seem to get swing to work with the technique of adding it to a JButton. I also cannot figure out if there is a viable ImageObserver that would animate the .gif in the drawImage() call.

I am willing to try anything, but I am most interested in the possibility of making the draw call work with an ImageObserver as that would be only a small change.

Thanks all!

Comment: If you're hell bent on using `ImageIO` (which I prefer) with animated gifs, you might like to check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188940/gif-image-doesnt-moves-on-adding-it-to-the-jtabbed-pane/22190844#22190844) out, beware, it's not a complete solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I already have it fully functioning as a BufferedImage, but as expected it shows only the first frame"

This will happen when trying to read the image with `ImageIO.read(...)`. If you read it with `new ImageIcon(...).getImage()`, you'll get the gif animation. See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22240487/2587435).

> "I also cannot figure out if there is a viable ImageObserver that would animate the .gif in the drawImage() call."

The `ImageObserver` is the component you are painting on. So instead of using `drawImage(..., null)`, you should be using `drawImage(..., this)`

> "I am willing to try anything, but I am most interested in the possibility of making the draw call work with an ImageObserver as that would be only a small change."

Combine the two points above and you got your answer.

---

Give this code a test run. gif image taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493961/2587435)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGif {

    public TestGif() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new GifPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class GifPanel extends JPanel {
        Image image;
        {
            try {
                image = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKfdp.gif")).getImage();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestGif.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) 
                    : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestGif();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful, and I think you found just what I was looking for! Thanks!